# Debug ArcMap 10.3 start - process ends with 'Loading Document...' message

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3

How can I debug the initial process of **ArcMap 10.3.1 for Desktop**?

The `ARCMAP.exe` process get's killed after hanging a while with the "**Loading Document...**" message.

[image]

What I have done so far:

- Check and reset the Normal.mxt
- Reset AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.3
- reinstall ArcGIS 10.3.1

It seams like something is blocking the initialing process. Interesting is that the process gets about `~100000 - 160000 K` memory and then doesn't change anymore until it get killed.

[image: arcgis process]

Any ideas how to debug the start of ArcMap?

(*sorry for cross posting, s. [geonet.esri.com](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/171035)*)

Comment: If you open Categories.exe, do you see any non-Esri extensions in ESRI Mx Extensions?

Comment: are you trying to open direct to a MXD file, or just loading an empty ArcMap?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall I removed everything before the reinstall. There was a `ET GeoTools` from ArcMap 10.0 which I deinstalled too. I'll check the `categories.exe` tomorrow. @Midavalo I tried everything, the `normal.mxt`  another MXD and just a to open the `arcmap.exe` directly...

Comment: @KirkKuykendall when I start `categories.exe` I see a bunch of extentsions with [random names](http://i.imgur.com/0qqdFsx.png), `AGS Proxies` and `QGISDataProvider`. All the other extensions start either with the name `Esri` or `ESRI`!

Comment: Did you try the step in this doc? http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/45924

Comment: @kenbuja yes, it seams like it isn't the bug because of the python version...

Comment: And have you tried Repairing the installation rather than reinstalling? This helped one of my coworkers just yesterday.

Comment: @kenbuja several times, but thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 3):

Description

ArcMap unexpectedly exits during the "Loading Document..." stage on startup. No error code is displayed.
Cause

This can result from an upgrade to Python 2.7.11, which was released on December 12, 2015.

In the newly released version, there is a line in the code that makes the following statement, where 'PyWin_DLLVersionString' now is "2.7-32".

This statement searches for the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\2.7-32\PythonPath, which does not exist.

source: http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000012670

THIS IS WHAT SOLVED MY PROBLEM

Comment: I updated to python 2.7.12 and it worked! Tried everything else and this one the one and easy fix!

Answer (score 0):

I have simmilar issues - ArcMap 10.3.1 hangs on startup "initializing application" phase.

Solution:

1. Rename C:\Program Files\common files\ArcGIS\bin\ArcGISConnection.exe
   if it does not help
2. Reset profile: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/78692